# How to make a Bitmap image from Google Maps APIv2 Android Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps

I am creating my first android app and I have a Google map using the MapFragment and now I need to extract an image of the map so I can place that in a ListView.

I have both a full screen Google map in one activity and a smaller Google map that fills about half a screen on another, taking a bitmap for any of them would be fine, preferably extracting a bitmap from the smaller one.

Please without this my app is pretty much useless. I heard that it is possible in Google maps APIv1 by using `getRootView()`, is there anything that I can do to get a bitmap or a static map in APIv2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK as of now you cannot take a screenshot of the map. The reason is that the Google map v2 for android is based of an extended class of GLSurfaceView(and so is protected by Pro-guard). Because of this the usual method of taking screenshot is not supported.

There is an enhancement request open on Google bug list for this and hope this will be added as a feature soon.

For now, I would suggest to move down to API v1(if you can, because Google has also stopped giving out API v1 keys).

Comment: thanks for the information  , i'm gonna stick with apiv2 for right now, and use a url to google's static map and then convert that url into a bitmap, and it seems to be working now

Answer (score 3):

Follow [this link](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#snapshot%28com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback%29)

> **public final void snapshot (GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback callback)**
>
> *Takes a snapshot of the map.* You can use snapshots within your application when an interactive map would be difficult, or impossible,
>   to use. For example, images produced with the snapshot() method can be
>   used to display a thumbnail of the map in your app, or a snapshot in
>   the notification center.